# FlowTests giving error even though quasar file is in the directory

Tags: corda

Im following the corda bootcamp on youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46X55zv6dUY&list=PLi1PppB3-YrVq5Qy_RM9Qidq0eh-nL11N&index=17

After setting the VM options to "-ea -javaagent:lib/quasar.jar" at 5:15, I still get the following error

"Error occurred during initialization of VM 
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : lib/quasar.jar

agent library failed to init: instrument

Process finished with exit code 1"

The quasar file is in the lib folder, not sure whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to the jar file. Download the correct version of quasar.jar and try.

Comment: I'm using the cordapp template for java, it didn't have a 'lib' folder which contains the quasar.jar, so i copied the 'lib' folder from the bootcamp corda project. 
What would be the correct version of quasar.jar?

Comment: 1. Bootcamp URL: [link](https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp)

2. Configuration: 
    `buildscript {
        ext.corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
        ext.corda_release_version = '4.0'
        ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '4.0.42'
        ext.junit_version = '4.12'
        ext.quasar_version = '0.7.10'`

3. Quasar.jar download link: 
[link](https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp/blob/v4/lib/quasar.jar)